# Gill or Branchia

Tags: expressions, terminology, common-word

I am writing a dialog and I need to mention Gills (or Branchias), the respiratory organ of animals like fish.

I was wondering which one would be more common or casual in English speech (say, in the US), and if it's a commonly known word.

Thank you!

Comment: Speaking for the UK here, *gills* is a very well-known word, *branchia* the opposite. As for the US, well I'd be very surprised if the writers of "Waterworld" ever considered having any of the characters refer to Kevin Costner's branchia.

Comment: **'Gills'** is far more common in the US.

Comment: But _gill(s)_ is only used for respiration in aqueous environments, and usually contrasts with _lung(s). Branchia,_ however, will produce only a puzzled look on American faces, especially if pronounced correctly.

Comment: @medica Exactly! (I think your explanation answers the OP's question quite clearly as to common usage.)

Comment: The plural of *branchia* is ***branchiae***, not **branchias* as you wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Americans who would understand that word (Branchia) would more likely associate it with a region of the (human/mammalian) body than with gills. It has to do with embryology from a time when fetuses appear to have gills, and the body parts formed therefrom.

Please note that in the lizard, tortoise, pig and human embryos, there is a stage in fetal development where all have what appear to be gills. It is called the Branchial Apparatus.

[image]

Where in a fish, these will become gills, in terrestrial animals, they do not. However they do go on to develop body parts with the word Branchia- still attached:

> branchial cyst, branchial sinus, branchial fistula, etc.

therefore, in casual speech, if you are referring to fish branchia, use *gills*.

Answer (score 1):

Unless one is writing dialog between rather specialized biologists, gills would be the better choice.